# UpdatePanel or RadAjaxPanel in RadGrid EditForm template not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have a RadGrid in which I'm using an EditForm FormTemplate.

Inside of this there's a list (RadComboBox) with some companies. When a user selects one of these companies, it should fill another RadComboBox with a list of all locations.

At first I tried this using an UpdatePanel, then a RadAjaxPanel. Neither work.

This is a stripped down version:

```
<FormTemplate>
    <table>
        <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Company
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbCompany" runat="server" Width="250px" ValidationGroup="NewResource"
                        DataTextField="C_Name" DataValueField="Bedrijf_ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcbCompany_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Locatie
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbLocation" runat="server" Width="250px" ValidationGroup="NewResource"
                        DataTextField="location" DataValueField="Location_ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
    </table>
</FormTemplate>
```

How can you make this work? If it's impossible, please give alternative approaches that don't require much work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using ItemDataBound event on grid, i have shown the example to bind country drpdown:

```
protected void gridLocation_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Item.IsInEditMode)
            {
                GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
                if (!(e.Item is IGridEditableColumn))
                {
                    RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("dropdwnCountry");
                    LoadCountries(combo);
                }
            }
    }

protected void LoadCountries(RadComboBox combo)
    {
        //your defn goes here
    }
```

And to cascade drop down you can take the onchange event event of country like:

```
protected void country_selected(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)sender;
            GridEditableItem edit = (sender as RadComboBox).NamingContainer as GridEditableItem;
            RadComboBox combos = (RadComboBox)edit.FindControl("dropdwnState");
            LoadStates(combos, combo.SelectedValue);
    }
 protected void LoadStates(RadComboBox combo,string countryId)
    {
        //your defn goes here
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will check this when I have access to Telerik again (at work).